# Bad bounty comment window behavior

Tags: bug, status-completed, bounties

It's been like this for me since my first day on SE.

While typing text into bounty comment text field, when the text stops fitting, the text field (or the whole pop-up window even) scrolls to the right a bit to maintain visibility of the last few characters, shortly after that it forcefully word-wraps while leaving the scroll position slightly to the right, and creates the following visual artifact:

[image]

I'm using Firefox Aurora and this has been my experience for a long time.

Comment: Duplicate, but also Firefox Aurora, or any of the browser beta / dev stream versions aren't supported by Stack Exchange.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: Regular firefox has the same problem however